# How to custom sorting rows in a NSTableView and how to update sorted data to the NSTable in Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have struck with filter the data present in the NSTableView, what my scenario is list of data present in my NSTabelView, I want to sort rows present in table view and display sorted data in NSTable based on provided input.

### Example scenario:

In my table view contain 10 rows of data present in it with 3 fields in that 'name' is one of the field. If I want sort and display the data based on names alphabet order or filter data starting letter with 'a' how can I update the sorted data to the NSTableView. Please suggest any idea for update data to the NSTableView. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SortDescriptors property on your NSTableView.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/SortingTableViews/SortingTableViews.html